# lldb (Xcode) custom formatting for a struct with arbitrary long char16_t buffer

Tags: xcode, lldb

In LibreOffice, we have the type rtl_uString, which is (simplified a bit):

```
typedef struct
{
    int refCount;
    int length;
    char16_t buffer[1];
} rtl_uString;
```

As you might guess, the actual rtl_uString objects then have arbitrary size buffers, as indicated by the length field.

We already have a complicated Python-based summary producer for this. I.e. installed with

```
type summary add --skip-references --python-function LO.rtl_uString_summary rtl_uString
```

The Python code uses GetPointeeData(), GetUnsignedInt16() etc. But, sadly, it seems to cause hangs in the debugger in Xcode now and then. So I have had to disable it.

It is much simpler to just print the buffer by casting to a char16_t pointer, as in

```
command regex ps 's/(^.*$)/expression -- (char16_t*)(%1).pData->buffer/'
```

but having to type *ps foo->mBar* etc is of course a bit painful, it should be automatic, rtl_uString members and variables should be printed nicely as when using the problematic custom formatter.

So my question is: Is there some simple way to have rtl_uString values automatically be printed using such a cast of the buffer member, as in that *command regex*, without going all the way to a Python summary provider? I tried using *type summary add --summary-string* but I can't get the char16_t* cast into that.